# How can I interpolate based on index values when using a pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have demographic panel data, where each data point is categorized by a country, sex, year, and age. For a given country, sex, and year, my age-pattern has missing data, and I want to interpolate it based on the value of the age. For example, if 5 year-olds have a value of 5, and 10 year-olds have a value of 10, 6.3 year-olds should have a value of 6.3. I cannot use the default pandas 'linear' interpolation method because my age groups are not spaced linearly. My data look something like this:

```
iso3s = ['USA', 'CAN']
age_start_in_years = [0, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
years = [1990, 1991]
sexes = [1,2]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([iso3s,sexes,years,age_start_in_years],
                                          names = ['iso3','sex','year','age_start'])

frame_length = len(iso3s)*len(age_start_in_years)*len(years)*len(sexes)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'value':range(frame_length)},index=multi_index)
test_df=test_df.sortlevel()

# Insert missingness to practice interpolating
idx = pd.IndexSlice
test_df.loc[idx[:,:,:,[0.01,0.1]],:] = np.NaN
test_df

                                value
iso3    sex year    age_start   
CAN     1   1990    0.00        0
                    0.01        NaN
                    0.10        NaN
                    1.00        3
            1991    0.00        4
                    0.01        NaN
                    0.10        NaN
                    1.00        7
       2    1990    0.00        8
...
```

However, when I try to use `test_df.interpolate(method='index')`, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Only `method=linear` interpolation is supported on MultiIndexes.
```

Surely there must be some way to interpolate based on the index values.

Comment: I found a work-around, so I posted an answer below. The reason I'm asking this is because I'd love to see an answer that uses pandas built-ins, so I'll hold off on accepting mine for a while

Answer (score 2):

This might come a little late, but I ran into the same problem today. What I came up with is also just a workaround, but it uses pandas built-ins at least. My approach was to reset the index, then group by the first subset of index columns (i.e. all but `age_start`). These sub-DataFrames can then be interpolated with the `method='index'` parameter and put back together into a whole frame with `pd.concat`. The resulting DataFrame then gets its original index reassigned.

```
idx_names = test_df.index.names
test_df = test_df.reset_index()
concat_list = [grp.set_index('age_start').interpolate(method='index') for _, grp in test_df.groupby(['iso3', 'sex', 'year'])]
test_df = pd.concat(concat_list)
test_df = test_df.reset_index().set_index(idx_names)
test_df
                         value
iso3 sex year age_start       
CAN  1   1990 0.00       16.00
              0.01       16.03
              0.10       16.30
              1.00       19.00
         1991 0.00       20.00
              0.01       20.03
              0.10       20.30
              1.00       23.00
     2   1990 0.00       24.00
```

### EDIT

I got back to this problem today and found a bug in my originally proposed solution. When the multi-index is not ordered as it is in your example, the above code sorts your DataFrame by index values. To get around this, I joined the result back into a DataFrame with the original index so that index order is preserved. I've also put it inside a function.

```
def interp_multiindex(df, interp_idx_name):
    """
    Provides index-based interpolation for pd.Multiindex which usually only support linear
    interpolation. Interpolates full DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The DataFrame with NaN values
    interp_idx_name : str
        The name of the multiindex level on which index-based interpolation should take place

    Returns
    -------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        The DataFrame with index-based interpolated values
    """
    # Get all index level names in order
    existing_multiidx = df.index
    # Remove the name on which interpolation will take place
    noninterp_idx_names = [idx_name for idx_name in existing_multiidx.names 
                           if idx_name != interp_idx_name]
    df = df.reset_index()
    concat_list = [grp.set_index(interp_idx_name).interpolate(method='index') 
                   for _, grp in df.groupby(noninterp_idx_names)]
    df = pd.concat(concat_list)
    df = df.reset_index().set_index(existing_multiidx.names)
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=existing_multiidx).join(df)
    return df
```

Comment: If you reset the index, you get incorrect values though. the value in 1991 for age 0.1 should be 20.30, not 16.30. This method does interpolate across age, but the rest of the values in the panel's multi-index are meaningful

Comment: You are right, I totally overlooked that! Thanks for pointing it out. I amended my solution. Let me know if there are still issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this hacky work-around that gets rid of the MultiIndex and uses a combination of groupby and transform:

```
def multiindex_interp(x, interp_col, step_col):

    valid = ~pd.isnull(x[interp_col])
    invalid = ~valid

    x['last_valid_value'] = x[interp_col].ffill()
    x['next_valid_value'] = x[interp_col].bfill()

    # Generate a new Series filled with NaN's
    x['last_valid_step'] =  np.NaN
    # Copy the step value where we have a valid value
    x['last_valid_step'][valid] = x[step_col][valid]
    x['last_valid_step'] = x['last_valid_step'].ffill()

    x['next_valid_step'] =  np.NaN
    x['next_valid_step'][valid] = x[step_col][valid]
    x['next_valid_step'] = x['next_valid_step'].bfill()

    # Simple linear interpolation= distance from last step / (range between closest valid steps) *
    #                              difference between closest values + last value
    x[interp_col][invalid] = (x[step_col]-x['last_valid_step'])/(x['next_valid_step'] - x['last_valid_step']) \
                             * (x['next_valid_value']-x['last_valid_value']) \
                             + x['last_valid_value']
    return x

test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=False)
grouped = test_df.groupby(['iso3','sex','year'])
interpolated = grouped.transform(multiindex_interp,'value','age_start')
test_df['value'] = interpolated['value']
test_df
    iso3    sex year    age_start   value
0   CAN     1   1990    0.00        16.00
1   CAN     1   1990    0.01        16.03
2   CAN     1   1990    0.10        16.30
3   CAN     1   1990    1.00        19.00
4   CAN     1   1991    0.00        20.00
5   CAN     1   1991    0.01        20.03
6   CAN     1   1991    0.10        20.30
7   CAN     1   1991    1.00        23.00
8   CAN     2   1990    0.00        24.00
9   CAN     2   1990    0.01        24.03
10  CAN     2   1990    0.10        24.30
11  CAN     2   1990    1.00        27.00
...
```

Comment: This answer isn't great, because it will only interpolate a single column at a time, while panda's DataFrame interpolate multiple columns all at once, something I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
test_df.groupby(level=[0,1,2])\
       .apply(lambda g: g.reset_index(level=[0,1,2], drop=True)
                         .interpolate(method='index'))
```

Output:

```
                         value
iso3 sex year age_start       
CAN  1   1990 0.00       16.00
              0.01       16.03
              0.10       16.30
              1.00       19.00
         1991 0.00       20.00
              0.01       20.03
              0.10       20.30
              1.00       23.00
     2   1990 0.00       24.00
              0.01       24.03
              0.10       24.30
              1.00       27.00
         1991 0.00       28.00
              0.01       28.03
              0.10       28.30
              1.00       31.00
USA  1   1990 0.00        0.00
              0.01        0.03
              0.10        0.30
              1.00        3.00
         1991 0.00        4.00
              0.01        4.03
              0.10        4.30
              1.00        7.00
     2   1990 0.00        8.00
              0.01        8.03
              0.10        8.30
              1.00       11.00
         1991 0.00       12.00
              0.01       12.03
              0.10       12.30
              1.00       15.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
test_df["value"]=test_df.reset_index().groupby(["iso3","sex","year"]).apply(
    lambda group: group[["age_start","value"]].set_index("age_start").
    interpolate()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This takes the DF and resetting/undoing the index you made, and then split the DF using the correct primary key (pk) `["iso3","sex","year"]`. Then it applies the interpolation to every group using the method `pd.DataFrame.apply()` and our friend `lambda`: First setting `'age_start'` as index so the interpolation is very straightforward for `'value'`k for every group of unique p, and then using the method `pd.DataFrame.interpolate()`. Finally, resetting the index should be enough to get the final interpolation.

Finally, I have done this also because I was looking for doing the same, but for many columns. Using your same code, the approach would be the same, but in a very simple for-loop:

```py
for n in range(1,32):
    col="value"+str(n)
    test_df[col] = test_df.reset_index().groupby(["iso3","sex","year"]).apply(
        lambda group: group[["age_start",col]].set_index("age_start").interpolate()
    ).reset_index(drop=True)[col]
```